# Make a loop with mediaPlayer -Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I do have  4 ToggleButtons in my application. All of them are for looping sounds in app. So, it means when I want to click on first ToggleButoon and its state will be on, music starts playing and keep *looping* untill its state is *ON*. The same with the rest of ToggleButtons. They might be *ON* at the same time (all of them) , so I'm planning to have 4 mediaplayers looping.
Here is my peace of code for first TogglleButton, so far no luck even with one....

```
    public MediaPlayer resourcePlayer;
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    resourcePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext,R.raw.loop1);
    .....
    .....
    public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.toggleButton1:
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();

    if (on) {
    resourcePlayer.start();
    resourcePlayer.setLooping(true)
    }
    else {
    resourcePlayer.stop();
    }

    break;
    }
```

When I click on ToggleButton nothing happens, only states are changing on phone as i can see, LogCat is also *clear*. Thanks )
UPD1: Now it's looping, but when I change state it doesnt stop and keeps looping.
UPD2: resourcePlayer is a public in Main activity
UPD3: I have take out MediaPlayer variables to onCreate menthod so to do not make a duplicates. It plays and stops but only first time after that Logcat is giving error messages

```
    MediaPlayer start called in state 0
    ....
    ....
    MediaPlayer stop called in state 0
```

Comment: have you tried inserting some logs inside your case statement?

Comment: @artsylar, i didnt get you. The following code on top doesnt play anything, somewhere is mistake and i dont knew where

Comment: what I'm trying to say is, does it even go to the case statement you posted above. have you confirmed that start() is really being called? have you checked what is the status of the mediaplayer?

Comment: @artsylar, well very stupid, togglebutton was without onClick, thanks)  Now it plays, but when i change state back to off, it doesnt stop, so when i click few more there are a lot of copies of this loops are starting and i CANT stop them, so turning off my phone.. god

Comment: at least now you know where the problem is. :) just don't forget to release your mediaplayer instance.

Comment: i think it's because you keep on creating a new instance of the mediaplayer. so you are always sending the stop command to the newly created mediaplayer object not to the one currently playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's because you keep on creating a new instance of the mediaplayer. so you are always sending the stop command to the newly created mediaplayer object not to the one currently playing.

Comment: ok, and how to do it right? I have to say it is my first project that im working on.)

Comment: I just realized that you are answering to me, i thought it is previous akash is answering :) I have updated my question.

Comment: here's a sample source code and tutorial about MediaPlayer. I think you can learn something from it. You also need to know about the states of mediaplayer. there are some rules so please check its API. http://alucard1990.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Make-a-Simple-Media-Player-for-Android I'll get back to you later.

Comment: I was not supposed to use resourcePlayer.stop();. Instead of it should be resourcePlayer. pause();. Thanks for help)

Comment: "Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state. Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again." accdg. to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work! Good luck with your app! :)

Comment: I thought i need to call prepare only if i will load music from sd card,internet... seems after stop also. Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use resourcePlayer.setLooping(true); or false

for your UPD3:

because you are stopping the resourcePlayer it needs to be reassigned the sound source but in your case it only assigns in oncreate method which only called first time. so every time you want to play after stop need to reinitialize it.

Comment: it doesnt even start playing any sound.

Comment: if (on) {
    resourcePlayer.start();
    resourcePlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
    else {
    resourcePlayer.stop();
    }

Comment: for next issue you can use resourcePlayer.reset();

Comment: actually, it doesnt stop at all. When i change state of togglebutton it still keeps playing, and if click more it plays again and again...

Comment: this is because in the onclick method you are creating new mediaplayer every time the button click and using it locally, what you have to do is create a MediaPlayer resourcePlayer; a global variable and use it instead of inside onclick method 
if (on) {
resourcePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext,R.raw.loop1);
resourcePlayer.start();
    resourcePlayer.setLooping(true)
    }
    else {
    resourcePlayer.stop();
    }

Comment: actually it is global, in my case

Comment: @Daler, based on the source code you posted above, you declared resoucePlayer inside onClick() method. So, it is not global in your class.

Comment: sorry didn't notice you updated your question. so what is the problem now with your app?

Comment: even if you made your resourcePlayer variable global. you are still assigning a new instance of MediaPlayer to it everytime onClick() is called. Please review your source first. better check if the variable is null or not before assigning a new instance of MediaPlayer to it.

Comment: as i said, when i click first time it plays and its looping, so when i want to stop--> it doesnt work. So, if i click again, the second copy of loop starts together with the first one, and so on so on..

Comment: please see my last comment.